# Making app for Offline Browsing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c and still learning. I am making an app for my project in which user can download the whole website or webpage for later browsing..so i need some guidance, so if any one can give some suggestion that would be great

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you asked for. Either by saving the websites data in temporary folder or you may save the whole site as pdf.